# Trying to send a login form input to database using html and nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to create a login page using html and node.js. I have been able to send stuff to the database using only node.js and postman but now I am trying to get it working with my html page. When trying to send stuff, I get sent back to index.html and a scripts.js error. The scripts.js error comes from the index.html page but it only happens when I get redirected. That error is not my problem though because I cant even get my db to update which is the biggest part I am trying to solve.

app.js

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'));
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

app.use('/api/user', authRoute);
app.use('/api/posts', postRoute);
```

I am using a routes folder where I contain the auth.js. auth.js also contains the methods I use to login in and registering a account

auth.js

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const { registerValidation, loginValidation } = require('../validation');
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {...}
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {...}
```

register.html

```
        <form action="/" method="/api/user/register">
            <input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwrd" id="password" required>
            <!-- <input type="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" required> -->
            <!--<button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>-->
            <input type="submit" value="Continue">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using postman when I need to register a account I do

```
http://localhost:3000/api/user/register 
{
    "name": "POST MAN",
    "email": "RDM@EMAIL.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Similar to login except I do /login and only use email and password. If I can get the register part working than I would be able to get the rest working as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying Form tag’s attributes in html

action=“BE URL or api Path”
method=“POST”

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: OMG it worked. I also had to remove `const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');` from my app.js. It was causing giving me a cannot POST message.

Comment: Now I got to figure out how to redirect user back to the website homepage and display username instead on login.

Comment: Res.redirect function try that  link: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/redirect